# Change background of rows based on a variable

Tags: xaml

I'm having some trouble changing the background based on a variable. I have tried several things and I thought this would work but it says background is not defined. Am I putting this too early or is there a bigger problem?

```
<RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition.Style>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RowData.Row.Priority}" Value="H">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RowData.Row.Priority}" Value="A">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </RowDefinition.Style>
</RowDefinition>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use converter which as imput you post your variable, ans as result you return color which is binded to property, more about converters: https://www.wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html